Nested Stack.Navigator not showing on screen
I have a nested <Stack.Navigator> which is not a direct Child of the parent <Stack.Navigator>. I have added Views and some Styling Wrappers inbetween. Can anybody see why it is not rendering? Is that not allowed? Do I need a second NavigationContainer for the nested Navigator?
I wrapped all my app in a NavigationContainer using a HOC:
export const withRouter = (component) => () =>
  (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Suspense fallback="Loading...">{component()}</Suspense>
    </NavigationContainer>
  )


The parent Navigator:
const getPublicNavigation = (Stack, screens) => {
  const { logIn, register, forgotPass } = screens

  return (
    <>
      <Stack.Screen name="LogIn" component={logIn} options={{ title: '' }} />
      <Stack.Screen
        name="Register"
        component={register}
        options={{ title: '' }}
      />
      <Stack.Screen
        name="ForgotPass"
        component={forgotPass}
        options={{ title: '' }}
      />
    </>
  )
}

const Routing = ({ _onLogout }) => {
  const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator()

  const guestScreens = {
    logIn: LoginScreen,
    register: RegisterScreen,
    forgotPass: ForgotPassScreen,
  }

  return (
    <Stack.Navigator
      screenOptions={mainNavigationConfig}
      options={navigationTransitionConfig}
    >
      {getPublicNavigation(Stack, guestScreens)}
    </Stack.Navigator>
  )
}

export default memo(Routing)

So far all good.
Now I want to add a multi-step form inside the RegisterScreen, using another Stack.
The Children (the ones that wont render). Note that "RegisterScreen" is a screen from the parent Navigator:
The code below shows just a blank page. No errors logged. Console.logs working in all pages. Only the <Stack.Screen> components from the nested Navigator wont render.
const getRegisterStepNavigation = (Stack, registerStepScreens) => {
  const { step1, step2 } = registerStepScreens

  return (
    <>
      <Stack.Screen name="Step1" component={step1} options={{ title: 'öö' }} />
      <Stack.Screen name="Step2" component={step2} options={{ title: 'ää' }} />
    </>
  )
}

const RegisterForm = ({

}) => {

  const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator()

  const screens = {
    step1: Step1,
    step2: Step2,
  }
  return (
<Formwrapper>
    <Stack.Navigator>
      {getRegisterStepNavigation(Stack, screens)}
    </Stack.Navigator>
</Formwrapper>

export const RegisterScreen = () => {
  return (
    <DefaultWrapper>
      <RegisterForm />
    </DefaultWrapper>
  )
}

Any suggestions to add a multi-step form inside a Navigator?
Any help or hint will be much appreciated.
I tried moving all the styles inside the children screens without success.
I expected it to work.
Resulted in the same as before. Over and over again.
